# Canvas apply different image patterns for differents drawings in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have 4 images to show in a canvas. I have 4 drawings in it. Each image for each drawing. But when i run the loop, it's applying last image for all drawing.

How i apply different image patterns to different drawings?

Thank you.

```
function draw(){
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

    var $width = $('#canvas').parent().width();
    var $canvas_width = 380;
    var $canvas_margin = 20;
    var $canvas_height = 810;

    var $total_draw = $width / Math.ceil($canvas_width);
    var $start = 0;

    for(var i = 1; i <= $total_draw + 1; i++){
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function(){
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo($start,0);
            ctx.lineTo($start + $canvas_width,0);
            ctx.lineTo($start, $canvas_height);
            ctx.lineTo(-380 + $start, $canvas_height);
            ctx.lineTo($start,0);
            ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, "no-repeat");
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            $start = $start + ($canvas_width + $canvas_margin);
        };

        image.src = 'img/samples/b'+i+'.jpg';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the same variable (*image*), the image.src changes every time until you reach the last iteration.

The loop runs his 4 loops before any of your image is loaded, then the last image is loaded and image.onload is called and draw your stuff.

To fix this, take everything outside the *for* loop and use different variables name. Or you could probably do something like that :

```
var imgArray = new Array();
for (var i=1; i<=4; i++)
{
    imgArray[i] = new Image();
    imgArray[i].src = 'img/samples/b' + i + '.jpg';
    imgArray[i].onload = function(){
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo($start,0);
            ctx.lineTo($start + $canvas_width,0);
            ctx.lineTo($start, $canvas_height);
            ctx.lineTo(-380 + $start, $canvas_height);
            ctx.lineTo($start,0);
            ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, "no-repeat");
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            $start = $start + ($canvas_width + $canvas_margin);
        };
}
```

So the *onload* function applies to different objects.

**UPDATE**

Hope you'll be happy with that code :) Sorry, I did not found better images with a sequential number.

http://jsfiddle.net/r5QAF/2/ Just merge this code with yours and you'll probably reach the stuff you want

Here some reading about the problem you were facing  (javascript closures in a loop) http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: I tried this method but didnt work either. Console : Uncaught TypeError: Type error. Because of using imageArray[i] in createPattern method.

Comment: could you post a JSFiddle so I can work on your code directly ? Thanks

Comment: Thomas, sorry i would but it must be 4 images available to show, because of this i can only do this : http://jsfiddle.net/r5QAF/

Comment: I'll have a look tonight if you don't mind :) could you post a screenshot of the desired output ? (with paint or whatever you want), and I'll update your code accordingly